# continuations in lua, is not working while trying extending it

Tags: lua, continuations

```c
    int resume_continuation_func(lua_State *co, int status, lua_KContext ctx) {
    int res;
    printf("gggggggggggggggggggggggg\n");
    if (status != LUA_OK && status != LUA_YIELD) {
        luaL_error(co, "Error resuming testMe function: %s\n", lua_tostring(co, -1));
        exit(1);
    }

    int nres = 0;
    res = lua_resume(co, (lua_State *) ctx, 0, &nres); 
    if (res != LUA_OK) {
        luaL_error(co, "Error ressuming testMe function. %s \n", lua_tostring(co, -1));
        exit(1);
    }
    
    return 0;
    }

     static int foreach(lua_State *L) {
      luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);
      luaL_checktype(L, 2, LUA_TFUNCTION);
      printf("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\n");
      lua_State *co = lua_newthread(L);
      lua_pushvalue(L, 2);  
      lua_xmove(L, co, 1);  
      lua_pushvalue(L, 1);  
      lua_xmove(L, co, 1);
      int res = lua_pcallk(co, 1, 0, 0, (lua_KContext)L, resume_continuation_func);
      if (res != LUA_OK && res != LUA_YIELD) {
        luaL_error(L, "Error calling function: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        exit(1);
      }
        printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
        // Don't close the thread here, as it may still be in use
        return 0;
      }

     int main(void) {
      int res;
      lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
      if (L == NULL) luaL_error(L, "Error creating new state. %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));

     luaL_openlibs(L);

     lua_pushcfunction(L, foreach);
     lua_setglobal(L, "foreach");

     res = luaL_dofile(L, "test_lua_continuation.lua");
     if (res != LUA_OK) {
        luaL_error(L, "Error running test_lua_continuation: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        exit(1);
     }

      // Close Lua state when done
      lua_close(L);
      return 0;
    }
```

test_lua_continuation.lua file contains:

```
     local testMe = function(k, v)
     if (v == 20) then
        print('aaaaddddaaaaddd')
        coroutine.yield()
        print(k, v)
     end
    end

      foreach({x = 10, y = 20}, function(tbl)
      for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
        testMe(k, v)
      end
    end)
```

I get :

```
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
aaaaddddaaaaddd
```

it cannot get into resume_continuation_func. I did whatever doc says, i can not get into the continuation function after yielding, this is one of my tryings, any sugg wld be great. I need this following pattern to extend lua's functionality.

Comment: Any suggestion please?